# wkhtmltopdf stylesheets

Tags: css, pdf, stylesheet, wkhtmltopdf

can anybody tell me how to include user-style-sheet  ind wkhtlmtopdf v. 0.10?

I'm refering to a local file, but that doesn't effect my Pdf anyway.

```
switches += "--user-style-sheet \User\...\style.css "
```

Comment: Is it an option for you to use another utility than `wkhtmltopdf`? One that has better support for using stylesheets?

Comment: No, our application is nearly finished with wkhtml.

Answer (score 5):

What about using a 'real' URL syntax with your switch? Something like

```
switches += "--user-style-sheet file:///User/.../style.css"
```

Comment: Just a note: you cannot specify multiple CSS files this way.

Comment: how to specify a single file.css with the linux terminal `wkhtmltopdf h.html h.css outpu.pdf` how to do this

Answer (score 4):

Another option to using the argument is to inject the stylesheet programmatically before the PDF conversion happens. Perhaps by using a URL parameter that identifies if a page is being fed to wkhtmltopdf or by downloading the page, injecting the CSS reference and then regurgitating the page for wkhtmltopdf.

Answer (score 4):

> In terminal

```
wkhtmltopdf -V
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.4
```

> Command

```
 wkhtmltopdf --user-style-sheet yourcssfile.css yourhtmlfile.html outputfile.pdf
```